# Suppress scientific notation offsetText in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with scientific notation on the y-axis. I would like to suppress specifically the offset / sci notation text, i.e. the `1e6` at the top of the axis:

[image]

This is *not* the same thing as simply turning off scientific notation, which would make the axis tick labels `2500000`, `2000000`, etc.; I'd like to retain the tick labels as they are, but just hide the little `1e6` on the top (because the axis label already says 'millions/year'). Is there an easy or 'correct' way to do this?

(The obvious hack I can think of is to simply divide all the data being plotted by 1e6, but that's not as easily generalisable, and I'm wondering if there's a solution that's less of a hack.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the text going wrong with a common multiplier of 1e7 or higher, it is best to divide the values by 1 million. A handy way is to use the tick formatter:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
ax1.plot([0, 1.5e6])
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x / 1e6:.1f}')
ax1.set_ylabel('incidents (millions/year)')
ax2.plot([0, 1.5e7])
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x / 1e6:.1f}')
ax2.set_ylabel('incidents (millions/year)')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: custom tick formatter]

Note that in older matplotlib versions you can't directly set a formatter function, and an explicit [`FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) is needed.